# How do I set the value of a parent object without knowing the path to its child?

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing an array which is recursive to an arbitrary depth. I'm trying to set the value of a variable in the parent object, but I only know how to set it for the child.

```js
async updatePrereqValue(value,path,name1,name2) {
        var itemData = duplicate(this.data);
        var data = itemData.data;
        var target = data;
        let coords = path.split(",");
        let x;
        for (x of coords) {
            target = target.prereqs[x];
        }
        target = target[name1];
        if (!!name2) target = target[name2];
        target = value;
        console.log(target);
        console.log(itemData);
    }
```

The `path` variable is an array of numbers corresponding to the "coordinates" of the target child. `name1` and `name2` store names of variables of the child.
When the value of `target` is changed, the value of the variable which is effectively `target` in the parent class `itemData` does not change, and I would like it to.

Comment: Can you add a working code with examples? The code that we can run. Otherwise, it's hard to help you.

Comment: When you do `target = value` it doesn’t set the thing that was formerly target to value.  It just changes the value of `target`

Comment: `async updatePrereqValue(value,path,name1,name2) {` is not valid javascript syntax.

Comment: If you are traversing the DOM, finding the parent is trivial with `my_child_element.parentNode;`. However, if it is your own system of nodes, you are going to have to create that attribute for that system of nodes.

Comment: @Countour-Integral, It's valid syntax if it appears within a class. `class Foo { /* it's valid here */ }`